# How do I offer a "sent action" from a custom class?

Tags: swift

I'm developing a custom class in Swift based on NSObject. It's a statusMenu icon/menu helper. When I receive an event for the icon being clicked in my custom class, I want to pass this on in the same way an NSButton allows to create an IBAction to respond to the user clicking the button.

How do I do this?

Code:

I'm registering a selector in my class to listen to clicks:

```
statusItem.action = #selector(statusBarIconClicked)
```

The selector receiving this:

```
@objc func statusBarIconClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("clicked clicked!!")
    // pass sent action on through a new sent action... how?     
}
```

I want this to be linkable to the user in the same way a button can lead to this:

```
@IBAction func myClassSaysMenuWasClicked(_ sender: Any) {
// Reacting to that
}
```

Googled for a good while and found: nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you're asking about this sort of thing, displayed in the Connections inspector (this is iOS, not macOS, but it's the same idea):

[image]

The question would then be: when the user selects an instance of my class in the nib editor in Xcode, I'd like those Sent Events to appear in the Connections inspector so that the user can hook up one of them and use the target-action architecture.

You can do this only if your class is a Control subclass. Thus, for example, in iOS, a custom UIControl subclass displays those sent events in Interface Builder.

If you can't do that, then the programmer won't be able to configure your target-action in Interface Builder. You can certainly implement a target–action architecture, but the programmer will have to set the target and action in code. (You could do half a job of it by making the target an outlet, of course.)

Comment: If I would change baseclass to a control subclass, how could I then go about making these sent events available to the user (programmer) as in the above image, and how can I fire these events from my code?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the comment above and googled further. I found the solution being to change from NSObject to NSController in this line:

```
class StatusMenuController: NSControl, NSMenuDelegate {
```

And run this command when I want to trigger the sent action:

```
if let theAction = self.action { NSApp.sendAction(theAction, to: self.target, from: self) }
```

The if-command of course checking so that an action is actually set before trying to use it.

I found no ways during my research to add any further sent actions. The way to go here seems to be delegates.